# Sorting with respect to number of postings using python

Tags: python, list, sorting, indexing

I'm writing a function that basically takes in two parameters as arguments, one of them is a list containing words and the other is an index for each of the word present in the list. My sort function doesn't give me the desired output

Here's my code:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import re
def sort_by_postings(words,index):
    for key, value in sorted(index.iteritems(), key=lambda (k,v): (v,k)):
        print "%s" % (key)
```

Desired output:

```
>>> sort_by_postings(['a', 'b', 'c'], {'a': [0, 1], 'b': [1, 2, 3], 'c': [4]})
['c', 'a', 'b']
```

Here `'c'` is listed first because its found only in one document that is `[4]` , whereas `'a'` is present in two documents namely docID `[0,1]` and `'b'` is found in three documents of docID `[1,2,3]`

So basically i wanted to sort the list based on the number of occurrences of those words in an order of least occurrence to more no.of occurrences.

Can you guys suggest any modification to my function or can you help me with a new function which provides the desired output..

Answer (score 1):

Why you just dont use `sorted` and a key that sort your list based on the length of corresponding value of your elements in dictionary  ?

```
>>> d={'a': [0, 1], 'b': [1, 2, 3], 'c': [4]}
>>> l=['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> sorted(l,key=lambda x : len(d[x]))
['c', 'a', 'b']
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in your code.

First, you are sorting the dict items rather than the words in the list.

Second, the sort key in the code will not produce the ordering you have described in your question.  To sort the word list, you should use:

```
sorted(words, key=lambda word: len(index[word]))
```

Third, your function is calling `print()` when it should probably be returning a list.  `sorted()` returns a list so you can just return that.